# Speed up SQL Server Fulltext Index through Text Duplication of Non-Indexed Columns

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, fulltext-index

1) I have the text fields FirstName, LastName, and City. They are fulltext indexed.

2) I also have the FK int fields AuthorId and EditorId, not fulltext indexed.

A search on FirstName = 'abc' AND AuthorId = 1 will first search the **entire** fulltext index for 'abc', and then narrow the resultset for AuthorId = 1.

This is bad because it is a huge waste of resources as the fulltext search will be performed on many records that won't be applicable.

Unfortunately, to my knowledge, this can't be turned around (narrow by AuthorId first and then fulltext-search the subset that matches) because the FTS process is separate from SQL Server.

Now my proposed solution that I seek feedback on: Does it make sense to create another computed column which will be included in the fulltext search which will identify the Author as text (e.g. AUTHORONE). That way I could get rid of the AuthorId restriction, and instead make it part of my fulltext search (a search for 'abc' would be 'abc' and 'AUTHORONE' - all executed as part of the fulltext search).

Is this a good idea or not? Why?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL 2000 and SQL 2005, it's absolutely a good idea to embed searchable keys into column that the full text index is built upon.  This is because, SQL 2000 and SQL 2005 do not efficiently handle what Microsoft refers to as [mixed query scenarios](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721269%28SQL.100%29.aspx#_Toc202506246).

In SQL 2008, full text is fully integrated into the database, and you typically don't have to embed other search keys in the data.

A note:  In your example above, you don't have to convert "1" to the word "ONE".  SQL FT will find "Author1" just fine.